# Using the Word Selection object from an excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am writing a macro in Excel that opens and manipulates a Word document. The code works when I run it through the vba editor in word but when I import the lines of code into my excel macro I get a run-time 438 error.

Word Macro

```
Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```

Code inserted into Excel macro, with wtemp being the word document object

```
wtemp.Activate
wtemp.Tables(3).Select
wtemp.Activate
wtemp.Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```

I believe the issue lies with the selection object, or that I am missing a reference. The references that I have included in VBAProject are:

- Visual Basic for Application
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Objects Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Office Library
- Microsoft Word 16.0 Office Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document object doesn't have a `Selection` property, but the Word Application does.

If you have a reference to the Word Application, you can use code like this:

```
Dim wd As Word.Application
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

Dim wtemp As Word.Document
Set wtemp = wd.ActiveDocument

wtemp.Activate
wtemp.Tables(3).Select
wtemp.Activate
wd.Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```